# Webpage with flexiible navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a web page with flexible navigation bar,but once i shrink the page i don't want it turning into a hamburger menu,Any kind of help is appreciated below is my code:`

```html
<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm collapse-inner bg-primary">

    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-header">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">
                About
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">
                Contacts
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">
                Settings
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Maybe this is being caused by a  further above? Also you might want to get rid of the extra space in the 
`navbar  navbar-expand-sm` to
`navbar navbar-expand-sm`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but there is nothing above the navbar except the head tags.